# Image Source Assignment in Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file, upload

Im working on image preview before uploading with JQuery, it's working in chrome, and opera but it's not working in Firefox. Here is the code.

```
       (function() {
        var result = document.getElementById('pnlZoom'),
    load = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.loadImage(
            (e.dataTransfer || e.target).files[0],
            function(img) {
                                   var source = img.src;
                                   $("#img").attr("src",source);                    
                                   alert("Image source is: "+img.src);
                               }
        );
    };
        document.ondragover = function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'copy';
        };
        document.ondrop = load;
        document.getElementById('file-input').onchange = load;
    } ());
```

can anyone please help me to find the problem with src in Firefox and IE . or any other better working solution in all five major browsers?

Comment: What does Fx say or do? Where does loadImage come from?

Comment: Perhaps you want this link http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can find the image without a problem then just use plain DOM methods:

```
source = img.getAttribute("source"); //where img is a variable
```

If you cannot find img then you need to do that first.